# beamer: How to get top-alignment if working with columns?

Tags: beamer

How can I top-align the content of the columns?

[image]

```
\documentclass[t,% top alignment?
]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% Background color
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!35}
% No shadows: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]
% No "Navigation Bar" above
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Frametitle}
\begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  This is \\ not top-aligned. :(
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \rule{3cm}{5cm}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's with a capital T.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% Background color
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!35}
% No shadows: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]
% No "Navigation Bar" above
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Frametitle}
        \begin{columns}[T]% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                This is \\  Top-aligned. :)
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \rule{3cm}{5cm}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Used  `beamer.cls    2022/02/08 v3.66`

From the user guide *12.7
Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns*

> `T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first
> lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If
> strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option (for
> example if a graphic suddenly “drops down” with the `t` option instead
> of “going up,”), try using the `T` option instead.

Comment: The difference between `t` and `T` is described in the [beamer manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) (section _12.7
Splitting a Frame into Multiple Columns_). Maybe you can integrate the description from the manual into your answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I saw that 'T'. Don't know why I did not test it here. :)